# Does text from cli argument need to be formatted in assembly? x86_64

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

In this application, I am trying to print a character passed through command line arguments (Intel Mac OS X). EX:

```
./thisapp q
```

Desired output:

```
q
```

However, it prints out a bunch of symbols and nonsense, but what is interesting is that different characters produce different gibberish. This leads me to believe that I am close. Does this need to be "formatted" for it to produce the correct letter?

```
.section __DATA,__data
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _start
_start:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp,%rbp
    lea -32(%rsp), %r10       #<--- should be argv
    add $8, %r10              #<--- should be argv[1]
    movl $0x2000004, %eax
    mov $1, %edi
    mov %r10, %rsi
    mov $16, %edx
    syscall
    xor %rax, %rax
    mov $0x2000001, %eax
    mov $0, %edi
    syscall
```

Comment: `-32(%rsp)` is definitely not `argv` because that's under the stack pointer (stack grows downwards). Maybe `+32(%rsp)` is, I am not familiar with osx startup state. On linux it would be `24(%rsp)` and you also need to dereference since it contains pointers.

Comment: After you push _RBP_, _RBP_ is stored at address RSP+0, RSP+8 would be argc (number of arguments), and RSP+16 will contain a pointer to the first argument (which is the program name), RSP+24 will be a pointer to the first parameter passed to the program, RSP+32 will be a pointer to the second parameter etc (up to the number of arguments - argc). `lea 24(%rsp), %r10` should get you pointer to first parameter passed to program. Since the stack contains an array of pointers to the arguments you would have to dereference them before being placed into _RSI_. So try `mov (%r10), %rsi`

Comment: 64-bit OSX follows the [System V 64-bit ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). In particular you may wish to read _Section 3.4 Process Initialization_ - and in particular **Stack state**. figure 3.9 is a good reference.

Comment: @MichaelPetch While OS X uses the calling convention described there, it doesn't actually follow the System V ABI. Notably it uses Mach-O instead of ELF and there are differences in how PIC code is handled. I wouldn't assume that the start up environment is the same because there's no need for it to be. OS X can't start ELF executables.

Comment: @Rossridge : I should have been clear I was referring to the function calling convention when I made that comment, however it also happens to be the startup environment on 64-bit OS/X programs does conform to the documentation provided in the System V ABI for 64-bit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's help I was able to get this working.  Here is the code in the event someone else is looking to do this:

```
.section __DATA,__data
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _start
_start:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp,%rbp
    lea 24(%rbp), %r10
    movl $0x2000004, %eax  
    mov $1, %edi
    mov (%r10), %rsi
    mov $1, %edx
    syscall
    xor %rax, %rax
    mov $0x2000001, %eax
    mov $0, %edi
    syscall
```

I would like to point out that this will only print 1 element (letter/number).  I still need to figure out how to get the length(size?) of whatever was passed.

Comment: You should comment your syscalls instead of just having these magic numbers.  a comment like `exit(0)` makes the code much easier to read.  Also note that `xor %eax,%eax` still zeros all of rax, and you can do the same thing to zero `%edi` (instead of `mov $0`).

Comment: Although in my comments I suggested `lea 24(%rsp), %r10` to conform with the way you did your code, it is preferable to access arguments passed on the stack relative to _RBP_ if you have gone out of your way to create a function prologue. After your push _RBP_ and copy _RSP_ to _RBP_ both are the same. _RBP_ shouldn't change in your function, but as your program expands (add local variables, push data etc) _RSP_ may change. I'd recommend at least doing `lea 24(%rbp), %r10` instead.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  That's true *if* you're going to make a stack frame in `_start`, anyway.  There's no point in pushing `%rbp`, because it doesn't contain useful data on process startup (removing a `push` will change the offset to reach other data on the stack).  You can `mov %rsp, %rbp` if you want, but there's no need.

Comment: @PeterCordes I modified my comment while you were typing. I added _if you have gone out of your way to create a function prologue_. I assume at some point the OP may be expanding his program, so I don't see the harm in having the prologue and epilogue.I'd agree for this MCVE it isn't needed.

Comment: `%r10` isn't an input to `write(2)` anyway, so you could also just `mov 24(%rsp), %rsi` to load the pointer from the stack directly.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was actually just working on that.  Is it bad practice to make a prologue in a small practice program such as this? I automatically do this whenever I am writing anything in assembly in the event I want to expand/reuse.

Comment: `-fomit-frame-pointer` has been the default in gcc for years now.  I'd say yes, it's silly in `_start` where you *know* you're at the top of the call chain, so there's no possible benefit to backtracing back through your function.  If you're writing in asm in the first place, the goal is max performance, and usually that means not wasting instructions on making a stack frame even in functions that are called by other functions.  For real use, I guess you'd want to emit correct `.eh_frame_hdr` info for a non-leaf function you wrote yourself in asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes you say that in    _start it is silly.  What is the difference between _start and _main in this situation?

Comment: @JLegendre: **`_start` doesn't have a caller**.  You can't `ret`, because `(%rsp)` holds `argc`, not a return address.  `%rbp` holds arbitrary garbage at process startup, according to the ABI.  (In current Linux versions, almost all the registers except `%rsp` are zeroed on process startup, since the kernel needs to avoid leaking internal state to user-space for security reasons.)  Apparently OS X process startup is very similar to what the SysV ABI specifies for Linux.